# Is it possible to send the location from Telegram to Bot?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, botframework

Is it possible to send the location from Telegram to Bot, which made in Bot Framework?

I send my location from my Telegram account to my Bot, but the server does not get them (I don't get the response).

Text messages send normal, and I get response from the server.

Code is very simple:

```
public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
{
    return message.CreateReplyMessage("Tadaa");
}
```

Comment: It is certainly possible to send locations to bots. I've seen bots built around this. Must be something in your server code.

Comment: how do you send your location from your Telegram account?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You have to look on `message->location` instead of `message->text`

Comment: @RomanCanlas: as usual: Telegram -> Attach -> Location

Comment: @fusion3k: I understand, but sent location do not reach the server :(

Comment: It sounds weird. Probably it is the server that doesn't understand the request. I've checked now (with last telegram vers and one of my bots) and it works as expected. Check on server side the full request.

Comment: @EugeneRazmanov: The official language of the site is english. For russian speakers, there's http://ru.stackoverflow.com :) Скорее всего, в серверном коде у тебя что-то не то, как заметил товарищ выше.

Comment: @fusion3k I do not understand what the problem. I delete my app in Azure. I use Bot Application template to create new app in VS, and I just change code in "Post"-method: `return message.CreateReplyMessage("Tadaa");`. I published app - problem still exists! I'm sending a text message from Windows Phone Telegram ap - Tadaa. I'm sending image or file - Tadaa. But when I sending video, contact or location - not Tadaa :(

Comment: In Azure I use free plan F1. Maybe it restricting something...

Comment: I can't help you on specific language side. I can just suggest you to investigate on server side behavior.

Comment: Found a solution? I know it has been four years, but the same problem persists. I can send locationrequest button, but when user clicks it nothing happens on my server. sending contact works as intended, but not location. why!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Dang it, this is a bug. We are filtering out messages without content and we are not treating the location property as "content".  To us it looks like no text, no attachments, no channeldata and so no reason to send the message.  I will push through a fix.